# Angular prerender i18n confusion

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

We rely heavily on angular i18n for localization.
Usually we would create one folder for locale using command

```
ng build some-project --localize
```

This would create `/dist/some-project/en/` and `/dist/some-project/de/`

npm run prerender outputs only one in /dist/some-project/browser/  ignoring --localize flag all together.
My question is: is prerender option still in some kind of beta? should we avoid it for now, or am i missing something here?

My understanding is i would have to create separate static pages for each locale.

Here is my angular.json

```
"prerender": {
      "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "offer:build:prod",
        "serverTarget": "offer:server:prod",
        "routes": [
          "/"
        ]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "prod": {}
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont think this is documented at all.
Took me days of googling/try-failing only to find answer minutes after posting the question.

```
npm run prerender
```

executes:

```
 "prerender": {
      "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "offer:build:prod",
        "serverTarget": "offer:server:prod",
        "routes": [
          "/"
        ]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "prod": {}
      }
    }
```

I needed to to add `"localize": ["en", "de"]` option to `server` and `browser` build config
Server:

```
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/offer/server",
            "main": "projects/offer/server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/offer/tsconfig.server.json",
            "localize": ["en", "de"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "prod": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "optimization": true
            }
          }
        }
```

Client:

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/offer/browser",
            "index": "projects/offer/src/index.html",
            "main": "projects/offer/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/offer/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/offer/tsconfig.app.json",
            "localize": ["en", "de"],
            "aot": true,
            "extractCss": true,
            "preserveSymlinks": true,
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "projects/offer/src"
              ]
            }... etc
```